# PHP Email Subscription, cannot post php file

Tags: php, html

Hey I have some trouble with my email subscription I'm trying to log into a textfile.

```
<!-- Signup Form -->
        <form id="signup-form" action="form.php" method="post">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
        </form>
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['submit']) === false) {
    $email = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['email']));

    $logname = 'email.txt';
    $logcontents = file_get_contents($logname);

    if(strpos($logcontents,$email)) {
        die('You are already subscribed.');
    } else {
        $filecontents = $email.',';
        $fileopen = fopen($logname,'a+');
        $filewrite = fwrite($fopen,$filecontents);
        $fileclose = fclose($fileopen);
        if(!$fileopen or !$filewrite or !$fileclose) {
        die('Error occured');
        } else {
            echo 'Your email has been added.';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I keep getting Cannot POST /form.php eventho the php file is at that path, someone knows what I'm possibly doing wrong? I'm quit noob at this :(

Comment: Do you have permissions to write to the file?

Comment: File is on my desktop, it's already made it should have permission

Comment: But your webserver is operating as someone else. Do your scripts have permission? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Why are you trying to manage an email list in a flat file, if I may ask?

Comment: [undefined index *blah blah blah*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: @JayBlanchard now I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ergh something must be up with my wamp server

Comment: @Blake for educational purposes, someone once told me to code to learn instead of learning to code

Comment: @user3249666 I develop to learn.. but to learn how to properly approach a problem in a way that is fast, secure, and easy to manage. Just because you can, doesn't necessarily mean you should :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I restarted my pc, with the code added I still only get Cannot POST /form.php

Comment: [this will never happen `if(empty($_POST['submit']) === false)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) - *"ain't that right Sam?"* - @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 2):

First of all add name attribute to your submit button, as in POST you will not get the form value of "submit" and your code will never go further

```html
  <form id="signup-form" action="form.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

Now in your php code, you just need to check $_POST['submit'] in if condition and you have also done a typo, you have used a variable $fopen which is not defined, change that.

```
<?php
   if($_POST['submit']) {
        $email = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
        $logname = 'email.txt';
        $logcontents = file_get_contents($logname);

        if(strpos($logcontents,$email)) {
            die('You are already subscribed.');
        } else {
            $filecontents = $email.',';
            $fileopen = fopen($logname,'a+');
            $filewrite = fwrite($fileopen,$filecontents);
            $fileclose = fclose($fileopen);
            if(!$fileopen or !$filewrite or !$fileclose) {
            die('Error occured');
            } else {
                echo 'Your email has been added.';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have not checked the logic in your code, but this should solve your current POST problem

Comment: The better (more assuring) way to check if a POST was sent, would be ``if ((!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'post') == 0) && !empty($_POST['email']))``

Comment: Yes!! I agree with you @ub3rst4r  this code needs lots of improvement, but posting an improved code would be spoon feeding i guess... :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I made the adjustments like you pointed out. Yet I still can't seem to solve my POST problem egh

Comment: can you post your code and the exact error you getting?